# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read property 'click' of null

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Displaying an error as

> (org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Cannot read
>   property 'click' of null)

Can some one help me out to solve this below issue?
*Clicking an element by Java Script Executor*

Java Script Executor method to click:

```
public static void ClickByJS(WebElement element, WebDriver driver){      
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
}
```

Worked with `(driver.findElement By(Xpath))` this way:

```
WebElement titleDD = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@aria- 
owns='registrationPageTitleSelect-dropdown-list']"));
ClickByJS(titleDD, driver);
public static void ClickByJS(WebElement element, WebDriver driver)
{
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
 }
```

Displaying an error when I used `(FindBy())`

```
@FindBy(xpath="//div[@aria-owns='registrationPageTitleSelect-dropdown- 
list']")
WebElement SelectTitleDropDown;

public void ValidateSelectTitle() 
{
   ClickByJS(SelectTitleDropDown, driver);
}
```

Comment: WebDriver may not have initialized?

Comment: Page Factory Object needs to be initialized. Can you check the initialization part?

Comment: @ShakamuriShaka Any reason for `JSClick()` instead of the stronger and proven `click()`?

Comment: Check you use PageFactory correct

Comment: It worked for me, Thank you @Subburaj,@yong
I modified PageFactory initializing part, (**removed void**)

         public void RegistrationPage() {
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
   }
         To 
           public RegistrationPage() {
  PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }